# Equipment question

Tags: binoculars, refractor-telescope

I'm looking to get some optical equipment that will be used for both terrestrial and astronomical viewing (ratio 70/30).  It will also have to be portable to a degree although I realise that with a proper mount it wont be able to be carried for long distances.  I've a long held interest in astronomy but never had anything more powerful that 10x50 binoculars.  I've no great leaning to what I want to view but I do understand that planetary viewing might be limited with the items above compared to more dedicated gear but as there does have to be fair degree of terrestrial use then that's always going to be an issue

I've narrowed it down to 3 choices which all come within my budget of ~ 350 GBP(including tripod / mount).  These are:
Helios 4x100 binoculars
Celestron 25x100 spotting scope
Startravel 120 OTA refractor (which has a correcting prism)

I appreciate that each have their plusses and minuses and that there's always going to be compromises so would be grateful for any advice.

Thanks in anticipation